# C++ - Exception thrown: read access violation. Variable was nullptr

Tags: c++

I have a program to read files from different locations from a folder. Once the file is successfully read, I assign the ifstream variable of the file to a temporary variable. Below code is an example:

```
while (!CBAsales.eof())
    {
        string sFilePath = "Datafolder/CBA/";
        sFilePath = sFilePath.append(sFileName);
        // Read the csv file
        infile.open(sFilePath);
        if (!infile)
        {
            cout << sFileName << ": File not found!!!" << endl;
            exit(1);
        }

        while (getline(infile, record, '\n'))
        {
            while (!infile.eof())
            {
                if (record.size() > 0)
                {
                    //insert elements here
                }
            }
        }
        infile.close();
        mapIAG.insert(pair<string, Vector<Stock>>(sFileName, V1));
        }

    CBAsales.clear();
    CBAsales.seekg(0, ios::beg);
    tempSales = &CBAsales;
}
```

This is the reading of the file. Now you can see tempSales = &CBAsales; where it is assigned to a temporary variable. I declared these variables globally and there is a pointer to tempSales shown below.

```
ifstream codeindex;
ifstream IAGsales;
ifstream CBAsales;
ifstream NABsales;
ifstream * tempSales;
ifstream infile;
```

Here is where I'm displaying all the necessary records:

```
cout << "Enter date of transaction" << endl;
while (!tempSales->eof())
{
    getline(*tempSales, record);
    cout << record << endl;
}
```

This is the error I get: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GwSuc.png

Why is it pointing to null even though it was assigned? Am I using the pointer incorrectly?

Comment: read this first http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @RichardHodges I tried to make it as minimalistic as I possibly could. The snippet is relevant to my question, hence I added those lines of code.

Comment: by minimal it means provide a complete 10-line program that exhibits the same behaviour, so we can reproduce it!

Comment: What about using the debugger? It's always a good start to work with exceptions, it helps you tracking the error throught the code ...

Comment: @Bentoy13 well I did use the debugger, that's how I generated the error given in the screenshot.

Comment: @RichardHodges: By "minimal" it means "as small as possible".  The bit that specifies it needs to be a complete program is, um, "complete".

Comment: remove all the bits it does not need in order to exhibit the problem. you need 1 istream pointer, an initialiser for it and a use of it. If you go through this process you will in all likelihood discover your own logic error. BTW did you use assert to ensure that the pointer was initialised? did you single-step?

Comment: @RichardHodges: I am not the OP!

Answer (score 0):

your loop makes no sense. If we consider only the relevant variables it is equivalent to the code

```
while (!CBAsales.eof())
{
    CBAsales.clear();
    CBAsales.seekg(0, ios::beg);
    tempSales = &CBAsales;
}
```

Either the stream `CBAsales` is at the end of file in the first test, which means the code in the loop never execute or the loop execute forever.

If the loop never execute the statement `tempSales = &CBAsales;` is never executed and `tempSales` initial value is unchanged.

Comment: What doesn't make sense about the loop? I'm checking the CBA file from start to end and then assigning all the elements of the vector into `tempSales`. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Your loop has no progress. you are looping on the state of `CBAsales` while modifying unrelated objects. As I said in my answer, if you keep only objects which influence CBAsales you have an infinite loop or a loop which never execute.That's what is wrong.